# Woocommerce default sorting is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce plugin with wordpress and getting issue in sorting. When i was try to sort with select option, page not reloading. I think this is some JavaScript issue, please help me to rectify his issue.

This is the HTML code:

```
<form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">
    <select name="orderby" class="orderby">
                    <option value="popularity">Sort by popularity</option>
                    <option value="rating">Sort by average rating</option>
                    <option value="date">Sort by latest</option>
                    <option value="price" selected="selected">Sort by price: low to high</option>
                    <option value="price-desc">Sort by price: high to low</option>
            </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="paged" value="1">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put this javascript function to your footer.

```
$(function() {
    $('.woocommerce-ordering select').change(function() {
        this.form.submit();
    });
});
```